# Generate war or ear

Tags: deployment, war, ear

I have a spring project include java project and a web project, and I don't know which packaging to generate EAR or WAR, this choice it depend on the application server or on the project?

Answer (score 2):

EAR is used to package web projects together with enterprise java beans so they can be deployed as a single bundle.

Since you use Spring I assume you don't have EJBs in your project so you can package everything as a single war file containing the jar of you java beans project and the spring libraries (with all their dependencies) in its WEB-INF/lib folder.

Most (if not all) of the application servers which accept EAR files also accept standalone WAR files.

Comment: So, can we package an ejb projects just in war file ?
if yes what would be the benefit of an EAR ?

Comment: ejb projects are packaged not in the war but aside with the war, together in an EAR. If you have an EJB and a web project, you have 2 archives: an EJB jar and a web project WAR. If you want to package them together to simplify the installation, you create an EAR which contains these 2 archives.